# Is it possible to use cookies to display (or not display) a pop up?

Tags: javascript, cookies

Background: I don't know how to create cookies, I just somewhat know how they are used>

Question: Is it possible to use cookies in an if statement to determine if a pop up displays?
Specifically, I'm promoting for an app. My boss wants a little pop up on mobile devices informing the visitor that we have an app and offering a link to download it. Got that working (code below). The thing is, it will pop up every time the visitor visits the homepage. It is possible to use cookies as a way to determine if it pop up should or should not display? I'm thinking it would look something like:

If cookie == new 
   display pop up

else
   don't display pop up

Please advise. I'm not that familiar with js or cookies (fresh out of college, feeling like I know nothing :| ).

Code for the pop up dialog:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if( /iPhone/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
        var url=confirm("Would you like to download our free application Data Breach 411?");
        if (url==true) {
            var url = window.location.href = 'https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/data-breach-411/id726115837?mt=8';
            url.show(); 
        }
        else {

        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use a cookie for the purpose.

Read  http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp for basic knowledge of cookies